# Create large model version in Google ML fails

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I've created a tensorflow session where the `export.meta` file is 553.17 MB. Whenever I try to load the exported graph into Google ML it crashes with the error:

`gcloud beta ml models versions create --origin=${TRAIN_PATH}/model/ --model=${MODEL_NAME} v1`

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.models.versions.create) Error Response: [3] Create Version failed.Error accessing the model location gs://experimentation-1323-ml/face/model/. Please make sure that service account cloud-ml-service@experimentation-1323-10cd8.iam.gserviceaccount.com has read access to the bucket and the objects.

The graph is a static version of a VGG16 face recognition, so `export` is empty except for a dummy variable, while all the "weights" are constants in `export.meta`. Could that affect things? How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 4):

**Update (11/18/2017)**

The service currently expects deployed models to have checkpoint files. Some models, such as inception, have folded variables into constants and therefore do not have checkpoint files. We will work on addressing this limitation in the service. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can create a dummy variable, e.g.,

```
import os

output_dir = 'my/output/dir'
dummy = tf.Variable([0])
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  saver.save(sess, os.path.join(output_dir, 'export'))
```

**Update (11/17/2017)**

A previous version of this post noted that the root cause of the problem was that the training service was producing V2 checkpoints but the prediction service was unable to consume them. This has now been fixed, so it is no longer necessary to force training to write V1 checkpoints; by default, V2 checkpoints are written.

Please retry.

**Previous Answer**

For future posterity, the following was the original answer, which may still apply to some users in some cases, so leaving here:

The error indicates that this is a permissions problem, and not related to the size of the model. The [getting started](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up#initializing_your_product_name_short_project) instructions recommend running:

```
gcloud beta ml init-project
```

That generally sets up the permissions properly, as long as the bucket that has the model ('experimentation-1323-ml') is in the same project as you are using to deploy the model (the normal situation).

If things still aren't working, you'll need to follow [these](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets) instructions for manually setting the correct permissions.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. My model is around 90MB, stored as constants in export.meta. The bucket is in the same project. Neither of the two instructions helped. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I think it's a model related problem. When I try a different model (an unrelated one, but in the same project, same bucket, different folder), it works. The one that's failing is an inception model with tweaked inputs/outputs to adhere to Cloud ML requirements.

Comment: The error message is indeed misleading. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @rhaertel80 I've the same problem. I've a export.meta, in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and i cant access it because i've got an error when Google ML tries to read a file. The error is : Create Version failed.Error accessing the model location gs://privateml-149013-bucket/model/. Please make sure that service account cloud-ml-service@privateml-149013-dc986.iam.gserviceaccount.com has read access to the bucket and the objects

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if it helps.